# If sterillising dogs and cats deprive them of sex hormones, does that not cause the likelihood of osteoporosis the way it does in humans?

Tags: cats, dogs, health, neutering

Someone told me that surgically removing these organs negatively affects their hormone profiles, and that people started vascectomising male dogs and cats for this reason, but I don't know if a similar technique has been discovered for those with uteri.

I know that humans usually take medicine and or hormones to prevent the onset of osteoporosis if they've had their hormone-producing organs removed for whatever reason.

Answer (score 7):

From https://www.clarkforkvet.com/dr-chat-articles/2018/1/2/deciphering-the-current-neuter-debate

"Osteoporosis, a common problem in women with lowering estrogen levels, has not been shown as an issue in neutered males or females, dogs or cats."